# Is there a way to access complete angular URL (with #!) in JAVA filter?

Tags: java, angularjs, url, servlets, endeca

We have many pages implemented using angular JS. We have created offline snapshot html and store it for web crawlers.

Now when a web crawler asks for a particular page, based on user agent value we redirect the request to a JAVA servlet which returns appropriate snapshot page to crawler.

When the request comes in to the servlet from a crawler (like Endeca), I just get the url till #.. and everything after # in the url is lost hence servlet is not able to return corresponding snapshot.

I know that its not possible to send complete url (along with #) via http request but I want to know if there is a way to overcome this issue.

```
curl -A "endeca webcrawler" "http://test.com/test#!/test1/id"
```

In JAVA servlet filter I get just `http://test.com/test`

Note: Google and bing bit convert #! to _escaped_fragment hence I don't see issues with those crawlers.

Comment: google is advising there is no need to do `_escaped_fragment_` any more and has [deprecated that spec](https://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html)

Comment: Did you get an answer? I am also facing a same problem :(